# Return ajax called content after browser back click

Tags: jquery, ajax, browser, tabs

i have a page with tabs.
And when user click the tabs it loads ajax contents.

But if user leave that page and turn back again i want to
show the last selected tab(and the content in it).

How can i achieve these and ideas?

Answer (score 1):

When the user enters a tab, save a cookie that contains the value of the tab they are on. When loading the page, check the value of the cookie and show that tab and its contents. If no value, show the first tab.